# JEST не обрабатывает pdf файл

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jest, mock, enzyme

Во время теста выкидывает ошибку SyntaxError: Unexpected token '%' из за pdf файла, есть ли правило для jest.config по pdf? Или как глобально установить правило к pdf на null?

Comment: эээ, а зачем jest должен обрабатывать pdf?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: @AlexeyTen имеется ввиду, когда я прохожу тесты, то jest пытается пройти по pdf файлу и возникает ошибка на спецсимволы внутри pdf

Comment: повторю свой вопрос: зачем jest пытается обрабатывать pdf? Проверьте конфигурацию.

Comment: @AlexeyTen а какая должна быть конфигурация, чтобы jest не обрабатывал pdf?

Comment: Ну вообще-то дефолтная конфигурация не обрабатывает pdf. Так что показывайте свой конфиг, а так же что и как конкретно вы запускаете и какая конкретно ошибка возникает.